# Removing @mentions using the 'tm' package R

Tags: regex, r, tm

I have a corpus of tweets and some of them have @mentions which I want to remove, I am using the `tm_map` function of the `tm package` but not getting the desired result. Here is an example:

```
tweetscorrected[[1]]$content
>@abc thank you for the treat
tweetmentionsremoved<- tm_map(tweetscorrected, removeWords, "@\\w+")
tweetmentionsremoved[[1]]$content
>@abc thank you for the treat
tweetmentionsremoved<- tm_map(tweetscorrected, removeWords, "y\\w+")
>@abc thank for the treat
tweetmentionsremoved<- tm_map(tweetscorrected, removeWords, "a\\w+")
>@ thank you for the treat
```

Hence what I see is any 'alphabet' is getting rightly removed but the '@' condition does no changes at all. But I want to remove @abc, @xyz basically any 'word' that begins with @.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It does not look like [`tm`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/tm_map) supports a regex as the third argument. What is the final output you need to get? Why not use `gsub` to remove all `\\B@\\w+`? Please add some reproducible code to the question body.

Comment: If I use `gsub` on the Corpus, though it works but it messes up the structure a bit

Comment: If I use `gsub` on the Corpus, though it works but it messes up the structure a bit  like `"list(content = \" thank you for the treat. https://./nkzy606vcc #clv #analytics https://./fsbwd03m8x\", meta = list(author = character(0), datetimestamp = list(sec = 51.526330947876, min = 8, hour = 9, mday = 3, mon = 2, year = 116, wday = 4, yday = 62, isdst = 0), description = character(0), heading = character(0), id = \"12\", language = \"en\", origin = character(0)))"` The data is pulled using `twitteR` and read to a Corpus

Comment: I guess you need to define your own `removeWords` function that will remove the mentions, and pass it to the `tm_map` function as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Taking clues from Wiktor Stribiżew one way to solve it would be

```
for(j in seq(stripwhitespacetweets))   
   {   
     removementions[[j]] <- gsub("@\\w+", " ", stripwhitespacetweets[[j]])   
  }
```

Source: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html